# Do any probability measure has to be countably additive by definition?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbabilityMeasure.html

Wolfram mathworld seems to define the prob measure same as a normalized measure.

Are there any generally accepted definition for a prob measure? I saw many authors simply assume that a prob measure is countably additive.

Comment: The definition of probability measure here looks wrong, particularly the part about $P[\{a\}]=0$ for all $a \in S$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Measure.html

Comment: A more reliable discussion of probability axioms is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms

Comment: @littleO In my humble opinion, the Mathworld definition does not assume the Axiom 3 in: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms

Comment: There is a lot of work on finitely additive probability.

Comment: Hmm, I deleted my comment because I need to look at the mathworld pages more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability measures are measures with some additional property. Measures are countably additive. Therefore, probability measures are countably additive.